# Does the congregation recite certain sections of the prayers if a mourner is in the synagogue?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, mourning-aveilus

This morning, a mourner (in *Shiva* period) appeared in my shul.

Art Scroll Ashkenaz siddur, among others, most likely, indicate that in a house of mourning, *Tachanun* is omitted and in *Uva Letziyon*, the phrase *Va'ani Zot* is also omitted.

I'm not sure if these rules are specific to when prayers are done in a mourner's home (i.e., does it depend on the location?) or would they skip these items in a synagogue where the mourner is present (i.e. it is based on the person)?

Additionally, if the mourner is the *Shaliach Tzibbur* (cantor), even if the congregation says it, should he, personally skip these?

Comment: I'd be surprised if the *avel* "forces his status" on the shul to make it a beis avel. Then again, we see something similar with a chassan...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky ... and "brit people". That's my impetus for asking the question. Though, my feeling is that since the instructions specifically say "in the house of...", I think it's the location and not the person. Let's see what, if anything, emerges. I may have to ask a follow-up based on why there would be differences.

Comment: http://baisdovyosef.com/faq/463-can-the-shul-become-a-mourning-house/

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Berura ([131:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.20?with=all&lang=bi)) writes that when an Avel davens is a shul or a different house, the congregation says Tachanun but the avel does not.

> אבל כשהאבל מתפלל בביהכ"נ או בבית אחר אין הצבור נגררין אחריו ואומרים תחנון ומ"מ האבל עצמו לא יאמר.

Comment: Thanks. I have to check if MB mentions anything about the other items in my question. I assume it doesn't apply.

Comment: @DanF it doesn't seem to explicitly discuss a case where he's the chazan

Comment: I'm inferring that the 1st part of the citing,  אין הצבור נגררין אחריו, is a general principle that applies to everything in tefillah including *Uva Letzion*. He just cited *Tachanun* as an example. I also think that if he is *Shat"z* the same principle applies.

Comment: Recent practice observed -- the mourner would say birchat kohanim if he is the shatz, but not say tachanun or lamenatze'ach (or the verses in uva l'tziyon) which the rest of the kahal would say.